# Xamarin Different Methods of Deployment (Ad-Hoc, Release, Debug, etc.)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

What do the different methods of deployment mean and what's the difference between them? (This is mainly iOS).

Comment: the release configurations are user-definable, so there is no real hard-and-fast answer to this

Comment: How can I define them?

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/demystifying-build-configurations/

Comment: in VSMac, Project -> Solution Options -> Build -> Configurations

Comment: @Jason I've noticed that my app doesn't work on my iPhone when the iPhone is not connected to my computer. Is there a Build option that can change that, or is it an app issue?

Comment: that sounds like an app issue, but based on the info provided it's impossible to say for sure

Comment: @Jason I created a simple application (click a button to change the text of a label). After I disconnect from computer and restart application it loses functionality. Perhaps I should make this into a new post?

Comment: I wonder if @SushiHangover can help with this too

Answer (score 2):

1. Release is used on-line and can be understood as having no print information like "Console.WriteLine("XXXXX");"
2. Debug is used in development time, and the version of debug has debug information.
3. adHoc uses the test version, allowing users to download the application from third parties.